# create database constraint assertion in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, laravel-5.4

In my shopping cart table I want to check that each user only can have one cart with false value of paid column
for example in carts table:

```
id         user_id         paid
1             1           false
2             1           false  ========> this should give me an error
---------------------------------------------------------------------
3             1           true
4             1           true
5             1           false  ========> But these rows are ok
6             1           true
```

Comment: Did you install PHP?

Comment: You should check for `false` value before saving to DB

Comment: @Amarnasan yes absolutely :D

Comment: @AhmadMobaraki I know that, but I want my database have the constraint that don't accept this condition :D

Answer (score 0):

Get the count using query, count the number of rows where paid = false and store that to a variable falseCount. 
Then assert

```
$this->assertLessThan(1, falseCount);
```